# Implementing ctpp / nginx for deployment

Tags: c, plugins, nginx

I've never posted here before so excuse me,

I am developing a test project that can provide a narrow set of information dynamically based on user input. My deployment targets include a select few low power embedded systems.
My application logic is mostly done, but I am having trouble getting ctpp to work correctly with nginx, and I'm afraid its ignorance on my part but I'm tired of banging my head on the wall and its starting to take a toll.

I've got the whole nginx / ctpp / ngx_ctpp2_plugin (or whatever its named) bundle compiling and running, and I can serve html. Getting nginx to serve data from a templating framework seems to be harder than I thought.

I can get ctpp to compile my templates from command line, or by linking some test C code to the ctpp2 library. I cant figure out how to actually serve the data with nginx, I'm getting a "500 internal server error" every time.

Ive already gone pretty far out of my comfort zone on this, my only other experience with a templating framework has been Node/jade. So if you know another way of generating some dynamic data with minimal effort with a small footprint on an embedded system let me know.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having is apparently a result of the plugin requiring an empty json response if it nginx is going to serve anything otherwise it returns a 500 error.

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://ngx-ctpp.vbart.ru/

Have yet to see it work, but this is the answer to the current problem.